Problem 5C.3 Isaacs' Finite Group Theory
I have a question about the following problem [Finite Group Theory, Martin Isaacs, Chapter 5]:
Let $G$ be simple and have an abelian Sylow 2-subgroup $P$ of order $2^{5}$. Deduce that $P$ is elementary abelian.
I report my reasoning:
From a theorem on the decomposition of finite abelian groups, I know that each finite abelian $p$-group decomposes into the product of a finite number of finite cyclic $p$-groups. If I apply this theorem to $P$, where $p=2$, I should get the thesis. However, I believe that this reasoning is wrong because I don't take advantage of the fact that G is simple. Where do I go wrong?

The structure theorem of finite abelian groups is not going to help much here. And you need to exclude the possibilities that $P$ would be isomorphic to one of $C_{32}$, $C_{16}\times C_2$, $C_8\times C_4$, $C_8\times C_2\times C_2$, $C_4\times C_4\times C_2$, $C_4\times C_2\times C_2\times C_2$. All of which are abelian groups of order 32 but not elementary abelian. I suspect this exercise is beyond me (I really should buy a copy of that book). What has been covered recently in the book, say in this same chapter? Look for clues there.

How can an abelian group be simple? Any subgroup $N$ of an abelian group $G$ is trivially normal, since we have $xNx^{-1} = xx^{-1}N = N$ for all $x\in G$

by the way, this is obviously a rhetorical question meant as a hint, there are ways for abelian groups to be simple

@paulina The group itself is not abelian, only its Sylow 2-subgroup. For example $$G=PSL_2(\Bbb{F}{32})\simeq SL_2(\Bbb{F}{32})$$ is a simple group of order $2^5\cdot3\cdot11\cdot31$, and has a Sylow $2$-subgroup isomorphic to the additive group of the field (so elementary abelian).

"I suspect this exercise is beyond me" & "should buy a copy of that book" : @JyrkiLahtonen : Does your Comment imply that "this recommended textbook is really good , though at a very difficult expert level , not for newbie level" in somewhat loose terms ?

Similarly the group $PSL_n(\Bbb{F}_{2^m})$ has a Sylow $2$-subgroup of order $2^{mn(n-1)/2}$, but that exponent is five only when $m=5,n=2$. And that Sylow $2$-subgroup is abelian only when $n=2$ (again forcing us to the above case). But, I suspect this question is to be answered without resorting to a census of finite simple groups :-)

@Prem I once had a chance to study a few early chapters of that book, and I liked what I saw. I reached a point where the material began to stretch my comfort zone. I wanted to go further but didn't have the time. May be "desire to read it further" belongs to the growing list of things I would like to have done earlier in my life (I hit 60 last fall)? Hopefully that answers your question :-)

Anyway, I guess that book is chiefly targeting graduate students (or very advanced undergrads) who take a special interest in finite groups.

Thanks for sharing that , @JyrkiLahtonen , "targeting very special advanced undergrads" : I get it : "newbies should steer clear of it" !!

As Jyrki pointed out in the comments, $P$ is isomorphic to one of the groups in the following list:

$C_{32}$,
$C_{16} \times C_2$,
$C_8 \times C_4$,
$C_8 \times C_2 \times C_2$,
$C_4 \times C_2 \times C_2 \times C_2$,
$C_4 \times C_4 \times C_2$,
$C_2^5$.

By Corollary $5.19$, the first five cases are excluded as possibilities. To eliminate the sixth possibility, put $V = \Omega(P)$ and $U = \mho(P)$ and suppose it can occur. Both $V$ and $U$ are characteristic in $P$ with $(V : U) = 2$.
Since $G$ is simple by assumption, you can use Problem $5.C.2$ to deduce that $|G| = 2$, which is a contradiction. Thus the only possibility is the final one.

Thanks. Now I really want to but that book :_)

I am clueless of most of this : Just wondering : Why not $C_4 \times C_2 \times C_2 \times C_2$ ?

Maybe it was an oversight. However, it falls within the cases that are excluded by Corollary 5.19.

Thanks for catching this. I have corrected the text.

@the_fox Thank you. I just didn't quite understand who we take as U and V.

Someone, kindly, can tell me what is meant by $\Omega(P) $ and $\mho(P)$?

You can maybe answer this for yourself. $G = C_4 \times C_4 \times C_2$ has only two proper non-trivial characteristic subgroups. Can you tell which ones?

$C_{2} \cong \mathbb{Z}{2}={0,1}$ and $C{4} \cong \mathbb{Z}_{4}={0,1,2,3}$. The only non-trivial characteristic subgroups of $G$ are $V={(0,0,0),(0,2,0),(0,0,2), (0, 2, 2), (1,0,0),(1,2,0),(1,0,2), (1, 2, 2)}$ and $U={(0,0,0),(0,0,2),(0,2,0), (0, 2, 2)}$?

Ok, then you should be fine here. As to the special notation I am using, see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Omega_and_agemo_subgroup

Perfect, thank you.
